# Magento2 404s on css and js

Tags: magento2, 404, deployment

Is there a list of command line tools to enter for changing modes? I went from developer mode to production and back again and now my css is all 404s.It doesn't feel like it should be this hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento cache:flush
```

See [Introduction to Magento modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)

Edit

Double check to make sure `pub/static/.htaccess` exist.

and try running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: No luck. My css is pointing to pub/static that throws 404s.

Comment: What mode is it currently set to? Are there any files in pub/static? Did you check the folder permission?

Comment: Developer. No files. 777

Comment: Is there a .htacess in pub/static?

Comment: No. I grabbed one from the github repo and put one in. Same issue.

Comment: Are you running apache?

Comment: I am running Apache

Comment: Try `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`